# Laravel - Cannot Un Delete and Display Data using Soft Delete

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I cannot un delete my data why is it? here is my code

on the ***Controller***

```
   public function displayArchive()
{
    $clients = Client::withTrashed();
    return view('admin.clients.homeArchive')->with('clients', $clients);
}
```

one the ***View***

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
           <tr>  
              <th>Client Code</th>
              <th>Client Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Tel No.</th>
              <th>Contact Person</th>
              <th>Mobile No.</th>
              <th>Email Address</th>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Update</th>

           </tr>  
           @foreach ($clients as $client)
           <tr>
               <td>{{ $client->client_code }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->client_name }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->address }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->tel_no }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->contact_person }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->mobile_no }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->email_ad }}</td>
               <td>{{ $client->website }}</td>
               <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a></td>
               <td><a href="/admin/clients/{{ $client->id }}/edit" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-primary"></a></td>

           </tr>      
           @endforeach

        </table>
```

on the ***Web***
Here you can see how I call my controller and view pages.

```
Route::get('/admin/clients/homeArchive', 'Admin\ClientsController@displayArchive');
```

***EDITED***
Here is the edited code please take a look
my ***Model***

```
 use SoftDeletes;

 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
 // Table Name
 protected $table = 'clients';
 // Primary Key
 public $primaryKey = 'id';
 // Timestamps
 public $timestamps = true;
```

Comment: Add your model configuration, maybe it lacks the softdeletes trait. Btw, is it any error shown?

Comment: @HCK I've added my model please take a look above the edited code thanks

Comment: $clients = Client::onlyTrashed(); . This will retrieve only rows you have deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with `->get()` method.

```
public function displayArchive()
{
    $clients = Client::withTrashed()->get();
    return view('admin.clients.homeArchive')->with('clients', $clients);
}
```

NOTE: it don't undelete any data. it only get data with deleted rows.

If you want recover deleted data, you must use `->restore()` method.

---

**For all restored all data;**

*Link:*

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.client.restore_all') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a>
```

*Route:*

```
Route::get('/admin/clients/restore-all', 'Admin\ClientsController@restoreAll')->name('admin.client.restore_all');
```

*Controller action:*

```
public function restoreAll(){
   Client::withTrashed()->restore();
}
```

**Restore row by row data;**

*Link:*

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.client.restore', $client->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a>
```

*Route:*

```
Route::get('/admin/clients/restore/{client}', 'Admin\ClientsController@restore')->name('admin.client.restore');
```

*Controller action:*

```
public function restore(Client $client){
  $client->restore();
}
```

`$client->id` is the client collection, I think you want to inactive in the listed foreach row, is right?

Comment: ok ive tried the `get` method but it gets all the data even tho it is not deleted. I just want to display the data that i delete on a row

Comment: For the only deleted data you must use onlyTrashed() instead of withTrashed().

Comment: I owe you a badge sir thanks! im grateful for you answer :)

Comment: now how can I restore my deleted data and restore it again ? for the final output? can you pls share the code and logic please thanks to finish my work today

Comment: if I want to undelete my data and return it back again how can i do that sir?

Comment: Can you try it: ``Client::withTrashed()->restore()->get();`` if it doesn't solving your problem you try 2 step for get restored data. step 1: ``Client::withTrashed()->restore();`` step2: ``Client::get();``

Comment: what if have this href button sir?  `<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a></td>` how can i implement that code to this button so ican restore the deleted data?

Comment: I edited my answer because my answer is very long for the comment area :)

Comment: thank you so much for giving me the logic sir, ill just adjust what ever the error may be but thank you for giving the logic